# WxPython How to make a Frame behave like a Dialog

Tags: wxpython

How can I make a newly created `wx.Frame` 'block' all other active frames, same as `wx.Dialog` does.
I want to force a user to make a decision (same as dialog) before letting him use any other background active Frames.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the wxPython migration guide on this topic here:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#makemodal

The gist of it is that you should use `wx.WindowDisabler` or something like this:

```
def MakeModal(self, modal=True):
    if modal and not hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
        self._disabler = wx.WindowDisabler(self)
    if not modal and hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
        del self._disabler
```